# Get the Count based on Conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have one table say `BrokerTable`

```
-----------------------------------
  BrokerCode  |  Rank  | BrokerId
-----------------------------------
   1527339    |   1    |  3880
   1527488    |   1    |  7550
   1527366    |   1    |  3854
   1527400    |   1    |  1519
   1527358    |   1    |  3862
   1527357    |   1    |  3863
```

Below is my part of query which calculate Business of Broker which are in above table. For example BrokerId 3880

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUM(T.Amount11))
FROM ( SELECT ISNULL(( CASE WHEN mb.PlanType = 'MULTIPLE'
THEN CASE WHEN mb.Mode = 'MLY' THEN ( ( ( SUM(SelfAmount) + SUM(UnitAmount) )
* ( SELECT bcm.PromoteeQuota FROM dbo.BusinessCalcMaster AS bcm
WHERE bcm.PlanType = mb.PlanType AND bcm.PlanName = mb.PlanName
AND bcm.Year = mb.Year AND mb.Mode = 'MLY'
AND bcm.MLY_From <= mb.InstallmentNo AND bcm.MLY_To >= mb.InstallmentNo
) ) / 100 )  WHEN mb.Mode = 'QLY' THEN ( ( ( SUM(SelfAmount)
+ SUM(UnitAmount) ) * ( SELECT bcm.PromoteeQuota FROM
dbo.BusinessCalcMaster AS bcm  WHERE  bcm.PlanType = mb.PlanType
AND bcm.PlanName = mb.PlanName AND bcm.Year = mb.Year
AND mb.Mode = 'QLY' AND bcm.MLY_From <= mb.InstallmentNo
AND bcm.MLY_To >= mb.InstallmentNo ) ) / 100 )
WHEN mb.Mode = 'HLY' THEN ( ( ( SUM(SelfAmount) + SUM(UnitAmount) )
* ( SELECT bcm.PromoteeQuota FROM dbo.BusinessCalcMaster AS bcm WHERE
bcm.PlanType = mb.PlanType AND bcm.PlanName = mb.PlanName
AND bcm.Year = mb.Year AND mb.Mode = 'HLY' AND bcm.MLY_From <= mb.InstallmentNo
AND bcm.MLY_To >= mb.InstallmentNo ) ) / 100 )
WHEN mb.Mode = 'YLY' THEN ( ( ( SUM(SelfAmount) + SUM(UnitAmount) )
* ( SELECT bcm.PromoteeQuota  FROM  dbo.BusinessCalcMaster AS bcm
WHERE bcm.PlanType = mb.PlanType AND bcm.PlanName = mb.PlanName
AND bcm.Year = mb.Year AND mb.Mode = 'YLY' AND bcm.MLY_From <= mb.InstallmentNo
AND bcm.MLY_To >= mb.InstallmentNo ) ) / 100 ) END
WHEN mb.PlanType = 'SINGLE' THEN ( ( SUM(SelfAmount) + SUM(UnitAmount)
* ( SELECT   bcm.PromoteeQuota FROM dbo.BusinessCalcMaster
AS bcm WHERE    bcm.PlanType = mb.PlanType
AND bcm.PlanName = mb.PlanName AND bcm.Year = mb.Year ) ) / 100 )
END ), 0) AS Amount11 , mb.InstallmentNo
FROM dbo.MemberBusiness AS mb WHERE mb.BrokerId = 3880
AND ( ( mb.PlanType = 'MULTIPLE' AND ( ( mb.Mode = 'HLY'
AND mb.InstallmentNo = 2 ) OR ( mb.Mode = 'QLY' AND mb.InstallmentNo >= 2
AND mb.InstallmentNo <= 4 ) OR ( mb.Mode = 'MLY' AND mb.InstallmentNo >= 2
AND mb.InstallmentNo <= 12 ) OR ( mb.InstallmentNo = 1 ) ))
OR ( mb.PlanType = 'SINGLE' ) )AND mb.Date >= '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000'
AND mb.Date <= '2013-02-28 00:00:00.000' GROUP BY  mb.Mode , mb.Year ,
mb.PlanName , mb.PlanType , mb.InstallmentNo ) AS T
```

In `BrokerTable` there may be any number of Brokers. I want to calculate Business of each broker from `BrokerTable` and get number of Brokers whose Business is greater than 15000.

I can use a cursor but as I told there may be any number of Brokers in table, query takes more time to execute. How can I get result in less time or easiest way?. Thanks

Comment: Did you realise that when PlanType is SINGLE, only the sum of UnitAmount is multiplied by the PromoteeQuota percentage? (Where PlanType is MULTIPLE, both the sums of SelfAmount and UnitAmount are multiplied by the PromoteeQuota percentage.) It isn't clear whether this is a deliberate feature or a bug - it looks as though there *may* be an extra set of parentheses missing.

Comment: @MarkBannister PlanType condition is correct. When PlanType is SINGLE, only the sum of UnitAmount is multiplied by the PromoteeQuota percentage and when PlanType is MULTIPLE, both the sums of SelfAmount and UnitAmount are multiplied by the PromoteeQuota percentage.

Comment: I find that SQL code to be completely illegible. Looks like a minification contest entry.

Comment: @usr: If you click on the `edited n hours ago` option under the question (which shows the edit history), you will see that the original layout of the query was clearer, but much more spread out - another user's edit changed it to its current state.

Comment: Ok that was an edit I do not understand the reason for. But the query is still far too long. It does not respect the time of the people answering here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT B.BrokerId,
       MAX(B.BrokerCode) BrokerCode,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), SUM(T.Amount11)) BrokerAMount
FROM BrokerTable B
JOIN (SELECT CASE WHEN mb.PlanType = 'MULTIPLE' AND mb.Mode in ('MLY', 'QLY', 'HLY', 'YLY')
                  THEN ( SUM(SelfAmount) + SUM(UnitAmount) ) * 
                       ( SELECT bcm.PromoteeQuota 
                         FROM dbo.BusinessCalcMaster AS bcm
                         WHERE bcm.PlanType = mb.PlanType AND bcm.PlanName = mb.PlanName AND bcm.Year = mb.Year 
                           AND bcm.MLY_From <= mb.InstallmentNo AND bcm.MLY_To >= mb.InstallmentNo) 
                       / 100 
                  WHEN mb.PlanType = 'SINGLE' 
                  THEN ( SUM(SelfAmount) +   SUM(UnitAmount) * 
                         ( SELECT bcm.PromoteeQuota 
                           FROM dbo.BusinessCalcMaster AS bcm 
                           WHERE bcm.PlanType = mb.PlanType AND bcm.PlanName = mb.PlanName AND bcm.Year = mb.Year ) 
                       ) / 100 
             END AS Amount11,
             mb.BrokerId,
             mb.InstallmentNo
      FROM dbo.MemberBusiness AS mb
      WHERE ( ( mb.PlanType = 'MULTIPLE' AND 
                ( ( mb.Mode = 'HLY' AND mb.InstallmentNo = 2 ) OR 
                  ( mb.Mode = 'QLY' AND mb.InstallmentNo >= 2 AND mb.InstallmentNo <= 4 ) OR 
                  ( mb.Mode = 'MLY' AND mb.InstallmentNo >= 2 AND mb.InstallmentNo <= 12 ) OR 
                  mb.InstallmentNo = 1
                )
              ) OR 
              mb.PlanType = 'SINGLE'
            ) AND 
           mb.Date >= '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND mb.Date <= '2013-02-28 00:00:00.000' 
      GROUP BY  mb.BrokerId , mb.Mode , mb.Year , mb.PlanName , mb.PlanType , mb.InstallmentNo 
     ) AS T
  ON B.BrokerId = T.BrokerId
GROUP BY B.BrokerId
HAVING SUM(T.Amount11) > 15000
```